# Cannot display image from URL

Tags: swift

I'm trying to download image from url using Asynchronous downloading method that I find in Stack overflow.We can see the image is downloading from the console prints[image] , but the image is not getting displayed in image view.

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I'm sorry ,I'll try not to repeat this in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFyck.jpg is not an image; it is an *html* page, as your own test tells you right in the console. So the call to `UIImage(data:)` fails and returns `nil`. The image is at https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIwzg.jpg.